# How do you access the properties of a related EmberJS object in a template?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have defined these two objects in Ember:

```
App.Course = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    students: DS.hasMany('App.Student'),
    courseComponents: DS.hasMany('App.CourseComponent')
});

App.CourseComponent = DS.Model.extend({
    course: DS.belongsTo('App.Course'),
    component: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I've created some fixture data for testing purposes and my goal is to display a list of courses. When a course is clicked, it should then display all the components that make up that course below.

So far it's all working (routes show the correct id for the course, etc, etc) but I cannot access the 'component' property in my Course's related courseComponent objects. The only property I can access is the 'id'.

How can I configure it so I can do something like:

```
{{#each component in courseComponents}}
    {{component.component}}
{{/each}}
```

It simply returns an empty string. The only thing I can output is the component's id with:

```
{{#each component in courseComponents}}
    {{component.id}}
{{/each}}
```

How can I access related object properties in a template?

Edit:

JSFiddle with my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/3bGN4/256/

Comment: there seams nothing wrong (at least from what you are showing) can you show your fixture data? or setup a fiddle with your code?

Comment: @intuitivepixel - Will do. The example I gave for the question isn't quite the same as my code so there may be a problem there, give me a few minutes.

Comment: @intuitivepixel - I added a JSFiddle with my code, a little embarassing but I've never actually created a JSFiddle before, only viewed others so I don't seem to be able to get my code to run. The code I'm using is all there, anyway.

Comment: Your jsfiddle misses handlebars.js resource. Check out the ember info page [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ember.js/info) on so. There you find preconfigured jsfiddles for ember.

Comment: @daniatic - Right you are, I used the preconfigured fiddle, pasted my code in and it works! http://jsfiddle.net/3bGN4/256/ The question now is... why isn't it working on my system? Using the same builds of ember/ember-data/handlebars and it's not working. :( Any ideas?

Comment: Aha, I pulled the handlebars, ember and ember-data js files being used by the preconfigured jsfiddle and it's working. My ember-data file was the culprit. Unusual since I pulled it from the starter kit just this morning. Oh well! This kind of invalidates my question.

Comment: Good question :) Did you just copy past your code or did you type it over again. I'm asking that to check if there are typos. Do you have the same revision?

Comment: Just saw your answer. I also once pulled an ember data build which didn't work, and I replaced it with a build from which I knew it was working and voila everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it turned out I was using a broken (I guess?) build of ember-data. I never really thought to check since I pulled it from the EmberJS site this morning via the starter kit.

Outputting properties of related objects is now working as I'd have expected.